# Parallel connection of V7805-2000

Tags: voltage-regulator, schematics, design

I am using [V7805-2000](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/670/v78_2000-1312985.pdf) in my design. [V7805-2000](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/670/v78_2000-1312985.pdf) is capable of producing 5V @ of 2A. Can I connect two [V7805-2000](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/670/v78_2000-1312985.pdf) in parallel to get 4A?. In this [datasheet](https://www.cui.com/product/resource/v78xx-2000.pdf) it is mentioned as "No parallel connection or plug and play" .

Comment: You could divide the circuit which is using the 5 V into two with just a common ground, if you can find a split where the current taken is reasonable for each voltage regulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, generally voltage regulators can't be paralleled, and in this case even the datasheet forbids it.

Some regulators can be paralleled, and they can have a special connection between them to communicate how to share the load.

The problem is the regulators are not identical, they have output tolerance. If one regulator outputs 4.99V and the other one 5.01V, the regulator with higher voltage output might provide all the current and the other one might be shut down.

Comment: That kind of things (parallel outputs) sometimes are dealt with by using (low) series resistances, but I don't think this is the case.